# What is the most elegant way to get a set of items by index from a collection?

Tags: c#

Given

```
IList<int> indexes;
ICollection<T> collection;
```

What is the most elegant way to extract all **T** in **collection** based on the the indexes provided in **indexes**?

For example, if **collection** contained

```
"Brian", "Cleveland", "Joe", "Glenn", "Mort"
```

And **indexes** contained

```
1, 3
```

The return would be

```
"Cleveland," "Glenn"
```

Edit: Assume that **indexes** is always sorted ascending.

Comment: @Bob, you asked for elegance. Eric's answer is correct and super fast, but having a method end with 5 * } ( } } } } } ) is not super elegant

Comment: @Sam, From google define:elegant - "refined and tasteful in appearance or behavior or style" I found Eric's answer to be tasteful in the way it behaves. The curly braces don't bother me. I also find elegance in the simplicity of the way the problem is solved.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This assumes that the index sequence is a monotone ascending sequence of non-negative indices.  The strategy is straightforward: for each index, bump up an enumerator on the collection to that point and yield the element.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetIndexedItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IEnumerable<int> indices)
{
    int currentIndex = -1;
    using (var collectionEnum = collection.GetEnumerator())
    {
        foreach(int index in indices)
        {
            while (collectionEnum.MoveNext()) 
            {
                currentIndex += 1;
                if (currentIndex == index)
                {
                    yield return collectionEnum.Current;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Advantages of this solution over other solutions posted:

- O(1) in extra storage -- some of these solutions are O(n) in space
- O(n) in time -- some of these solutions are quadradic in time
- works on any two sequences; does not require ICollection or IList.
- only iterates the collection once; some solutions iterate the collection multiple times (to build a list out of it, for instance.)

Disadvantages:

- harder to read

Comment: Looks very similar to my solution, too. Why did you choose to enumerate over the indexes in the outer loop?

Comment: Your solution takes advantage of the fact that the indexes are in a list; mine does not. If you start from the premise that the indexes are in an indexable list and the collection is a not-indexable seqeunce, then it makes sense to have your outer loop go over the collection and use an index to "enumerate" the list.  But if you start from the premise that both are not-indexable sequences then from a control-flow perspective it doesn't matter which loop "goes outside" the other.

Comment: But there is another aspect as well. In your solution, you have a "meta index" -- the reader of the code is required to understand that the indexesIndex is an INDEX into a LIST OF INDEXES, which is a potentially confusing "level mixture". In my solution I chose to ensure that the "index" stuck in currentIndex actually is an index into the collection, not an index into the indexes into the collection. It's a subtle point, but I think a good one.

Comment: It is - it makes the code even harder to read. As an author I did Not see this point, because I know what indexedIndex is ... nevertheless the basic idea is very similar - and my algorithm has all the advantages you are pointing out, too. And the disadvatages .. :) For me the idea of the implementation is most important - whether you do a yield return or an extension method doesn't matter so much.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good solution. Hope you don't mind the minor grammatical edit (and the modificiation to use `++currentIndex`).

Comment: Why anyone thinks that "a++; if (a == b)" is somehow harder to read than "if (++a == b)" is beyond me. I have two logical operations -- an incrementing side effect and a conditional goto. It makes it more confusing to combine them into one statement than to make them separate statements. Each statement should have ONE TASK. not TWO.

Comment: @Eric, this thing that would be most confusing to a maintainer of this code is the need for GetEnumerator. ofcourse if you nest two foreach statements this don't work. That fact alone would perhaps not be enough to deter an junior dev to "refactor" it to two foreach statements and break it

Comment: @Eric see my answer, for a way that evades needing to keep track of an enumerator, granted its a tiny bit less efficient than your solution

Answer (score 6):

Here's a faster version:

```
IEnumerable<T> ByIndices<T>(ICollection<T> data, IList<int> indices)
{
    int current = 0;
    foreach(var datum in data.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i }))
    {
        if(datum.Index == indices[current])
        {
            yield return datum.Value;
            if(++current == indices.Count)
                yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only works correctly when the index list is sorted, but that's part of the spec so you get an upvote ;)

Comment: Yep -- without the index list being sorted there's probably not any way to do this fast without either sorting it or making a copy of the collection.

Comment: Very similar to my version ... beside the .Select and auto-indexing. I wonder which version is more performant.

Comment: Probably yours is.  In my experience there's usually a little bit of overhead to LINQ IEnumerable twiddling as opposed to the "functionally equivalent" imperative code.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how elegant this is, but here you go.

Since `ICollection<>` doesn't give you indexing I just used `IEnumerable<>`, and since I didn't need the index on the `IList<>` I used `IEnumerable<>` there too.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IndexedLookup<T>(
    IEnumerable<int> indexes, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    using (var indexesEnum = indexes.GetEnumerator())
    using (var itemsEnum = items.GetEnumerator())
    {
        int currentIndex = -1;
        while (indexesEnum.MoveNext())
        {
            while (currentIndex != indexesEnum.Current)
            {
                if (!itemsEnum.MoveNext())
                    yield break;
                currentIndex++;
            }

            yield return itemsEnum.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Just noticed my solution is similar to Erics.

Answer (score 3):

I would use an extension Method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> pSeq, 
                                       params int [] pIndexes)
{
      return pSeq.Where((pArg, pId) => pIndexes.Contains(pId));
}
```

Comment: First off, the indexes are in a list, not an array. Second, this is extremely inefficient if the list of indexes is long.

Comment: A usual with .Contains, don't do this if you don't know how many indexes there will be in the collection. Or you'll go the O(n^2) way the hard way. If you want to be on the safe side, you should use a intermediary Lookup/Dictionary/Hashset and test on this collection and not on the vanilla list (linear search is not good for you)

Comment: My solution offers a faster answer.

Comment: public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> pSeq, 
                                       IDictionary<int,int> indexes)
{
      return pSeq.Where((pArg, pId) => indexes.Contains(pId));
}

called like this 

collection.Filter(indexes.ToDictionary(n => n));

It will be better with an hashset (less memory used) but you'd need a specific ToHashset extension method.

Comment: Mhh. Made it an answer proper.

Comment: I think the spirit of the question is that you are stuck with just a mysterious ICollection and you aren't to make a copy.  Otherwise, rather than make it a hashtable, it would be easier just to make it an array, and refer to it by index.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't pay attention to performance of Contains method.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in an extension method:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Extract<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IList<int> indexes)
{
   int index = 0;
   foreach(var item in collection)
   {
     if (indexes.Contains(index))
       yield item;
     index++;
   }
}
```

Comment: If elegant means "easy to understand" this wins... However, if index list is large, Contains() will hurt performance.

Comment: all you use is `Contains` on the `indexes`, so better to loosen up by accepting an `IEnumerable<int>`.

Answer (score 3):

Not elegant, but efficient - make sure indexes are sorted ...

```
ICollection<T> selected = new Collection<T>();
var indexesIndex = 0;
var collectionIndex = 0;
foreach( var item in collection )
{
    if( indexes[indexesIndex] != collectionIndex++ )
    {
        continue;
    }
    selected.Add( item );
    if( ++indexesIndex == indexes.Count )
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a proper answer :

```
var col = new []{"a","b","c"};
var ints = new []{0,2};
var set = new HashSet<int>(ints);

var result = col.Where((item,index) => set.Contains(index));
```

A usual with IList.Contains or Enumerable.Contains, don't do lookups in lists  if you don't know how many indexes there will be in the collection. Or you'll go the O(n^2) way the hard way. If you want to be on the safe side, you should use a intermediary Lookup/Dictionary/Hashset and test on this collection and not on the vanilla list (linear search is not good for you)

Comment: I like your idea of using Hashset

Answer (score 2):

Several good suggestions here already, I'll just throw in my two cents.

```
int counter = 0;
var x = collection
    .Where((item, index) => 
        counter < indices.Length && 
        index == indices[counter] && 
        ++counter != 0);
```

edit: yah, didn't think it through the first time around. the increment has to happen only when the other two conditions are satisfied..

Comment: This might work if the clauses in the condition were the other way around -- as-is, counter will increment even if it doesn't find a result, wreaking havoc.

Answer (score 2):

I find this solution particualarly elegant and a bit easier to follow.

**Solution 1**

```
   public static IEnumerable<T> GetIndexedItems2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,    IEnumerable<int> indices) {

        int skipped = 0;
        foreach (int index in indices) {
            int offset = index - skipped;
            collection = collection.Skip(offset);
            skipped += offset;
            yield return collection.First();
        }
    }
```

This can be refactored farther to a real simple implementation:

**Solution 2**

```
   public static IEnumerable<T> GetIndexedItems3<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IEnumerable<int> indices) {
        foreach (int offset in indices.Distances()) {
            collection = collection.Skip(offset);
            yield return collection.First();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> Distances(this IEnumerable<int> numbers) {
        int offset = 0;
        foreach (var number in numbers) {
            yield return number - offset;
            offset = number;
        }
    }
```

**But we are not done**

Due to deferred execution LINQs Skip is way too slow.

```
   public static IEnumerable<T> GetIndexedItems4<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IEnumerable<int> indices) {
        var rest = collection.GetEnumerator();
        foreach (int offset in indices.Distances()) {
            Skip(rest, offset);
            yield return rest.Current;
        }
    }

    static void Skip<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int skip) {
        while (skip > 0) {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            skip--;
        }
        return;
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> Distances(this IEnumerable<int> numbers) {
        int offset = 0;
        foreach (var number in numbers) {
            yield return number - offset;
            offset = number;
        }
    }
```

Benchmarking, gives us similar performance to the solution by Eric.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication21 {

    static class LinqExtensions {

        public static IEnumerable<T> GetIndexedItemsEric<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IEnumerable<int> indices) {
            int currentIndex = -1;
            using (var collectionEnum = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
                foreach (int index in indices) {
                    while (collectionEnum.MoveNext()) {
                        currentIndex += 1;
                        if (currentIndex == index) {
                            yield return collectionEnum.Current;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> GetIndexedItemsSam<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IEnumerable<int> indices) {
            var rest = collection.GetEnumerator();
            foreach (int offset in indices.Distances()) {
                Skip(rest, offset);
                yield return rest.Current;
            }
        }

        static void Skip<T>(this IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int skip) {
            while (skip > 0) {
                enumerator.MoveNext();
                skip--;
            }
            return;
        }

        static IEnumerable<int> Distances(this IEnumerable<int> numbers) {
            int offset = 0;
            foreach (var number in numbers) {
                yield return number - offset;
                offset = number;
            }
        }
    } 

    class Program {

        static void TimeAction(string description, int iterations, Action func) {
            var watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                func(); 
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.Write(description);
            Console.WriteLine(" Time Elapsed {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {

            int max = 100000;
            int lookupCount = 1000;
            int iterations = 500;
            var rand = new Random();
            var array = Enumerable.Range(0, max).ToArray();
            var lookups = Enumerable.Range(0, lookupCount).Select(i => rand.Next(max - 1)).Distinct().OrderBy(_ => _).ToArray();

            // warmup 
            array.GetIndexedItemsEric(lookups).ToArray();
            array.GetIndexedItemsSam(lookups).ToArray();

            TimeAction("Eric's Solution", iterations, () => {
                array.GetIndexedItemsEric(lookups).ToArray();
            });

            TimeAction("Sam's Solution", iterations, () =>
            {
                array.GetIndexedItemsEric(lookups).ToArray();
            });

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

```
 
Eric's Solution Time Elapsed 770 ms
Sam's Solution Time Elapsed 768 ms
```

Comment: Don't forget when profiling like this that the first time the code runs takes potentially much longer than the average subsequent times, because the jitter only runs the first time. Failure to consider that fact can massively skew results when the algorithm is fast but the jitter, for whatever reason, has a lot of work to do the first time.  If what you are interested in is the marginal cost of each run, rather than the amortized cost overall, then you might consider getting in the habit of doing the first call to "func" outside of the stopwatch timing.

Comment: @Eric, true, I should make TimeAction take care of jitting before timing anything, I did a warmup to ensure most stuff is jitted to work around that. I also tested this in both orders to ensure my results are not skewed, both implementations perform pretty much identically.

Answer (score 1):

I like linq.

```
    IList<T> list = collection.ToList<T>();

    var result = from i in indexes
                 select list[i];

    return result.ToList<T>();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, an ICollection may not necessarily have any order which is why there isn't an extremely elegant solution to access things by index.  You many want to consider using a dictionary or list to store the data in the collection.

The best way I can think of is to iterate through the collection while keeping track of what index you are on.  Then check if the indexes list contains that index.  If so, return that element.

Comment: You contradict yourself. First you say that collections have no order, and then you say "iterate through it". If it's not orderable then it cannot be iterated.  Collections are required to have an order because they are required to implement IEnumerable. That order need not be stable under any operation on the collection, but some ordering must exist. The relevant bit is not the ordering, the relevant bit is that collections are not required to have an index operation.

Comment: Your algorithm sketch is unnecessarily inefficient because it does not take advantage of the fact that the index list is already in the right order. Rather than searching the list, take out another iterator to the list, to keep track of what the next target index is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereIndexes<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, IEnumerable<int> indexes)
    {
        IList<T> l = new List<T>(collection);
        foreach (var index in indexes)
        {
            yield return l[index]; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: This algorithm is slightly misleading. At first reading I thought iterating over indexes instead of the list is efficient, but then,  copying the list negates the possible benefits.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the most efficient way would be to use a `Dictionary<int,T>` instead of a `Collection<T>`. You can still keep a list of indexes you want to use in the `IList<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but what's wrong with just:

```
indexes.Select( (index => values[index]))
```

Comment: Collections do not have an [ ] operator.

Comment: values is an ICollection, so it doesn't have an indexed property.