# .NET benchmarking frameworks

Tags: .net, performance, testing, benchmarking

Are there any .NET frameworks for writing micro-benchmarks like [Japex](https://japex.dev.java.net/) or [this](http://ellipticgroup.com/html/benchmarkingArticle.html) (both are for Java)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jon Skeet wrote one: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jonskeet/archive/2009/01/26/benchmarking-made-easy.aspx

It also lives on [google-code](http://code.google.com/p/minibench/)

Unfortunately, it not as rich as Japex

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047218/benchmarking-small-code-samples-in-c-can-this-implementation-be-improved, its not really a framework, but a method you can use.

Comment: I really must get back to it at some point. Probably not until the book's finished though...

Comment: All great answers should begin with those 4 words, shouldn't they?

Answer (score 3):

Check this out,  it is really cool library, VERY easy to use 
http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2009/02/06/measureit-update-tool-for-doing-microbenchmarks.aspx

The best feature I like in it is the normalization feature, it lets you compare different results in a meaningful way.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try https://perfdotnet.github.io/BenchmarkDotNet/, which's a good tool currently. I'm very happy to used it everyday.