# Performance measurement of .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory

I have converted 32-bit application to 64-bit. How do I measure performance of application in both versions.

1. Is there any benchmarking/ performance measurement tool/dll?
2. Is it possible to measure performance on module/functionality level rather than entire application. For example, I would like to see performance GraphicsRender functionality in 32-bit and 64-bit machines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try any profiler?

Comment: These can be helpful.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff647788.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449870/how-to-write-performance-test-for-net-application .. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

The one is available by microsoft for .net profiling is [CLR Profiler for .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273). You can use that for any of your .Net 4.0 application. For 2.0 the same profiler is also available.

You can give it try to [jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) profiler for performance measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ANTS Profiler: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

It is as a free trial period. You can install it in your Visual Studio.

Is measures how many time a method is called, it's execution time and also measures memory consumption.