# Continous Benchmarking Test framework for C#

Tags: c#, continuous-integration

I am working on a legacy software product, where we from time to time get's pretty close to shipping - or do ship, changes that degrade performance a lot. The issue stem from some old design choices where a seemingly innocent change in some cause can case a huge rise in database queries for certain tasks.

To be a bit upfront we would like to run some benchmark tests automatically as part of our Continous Integration build chain.

I have been looking for frameworks to implement test, in a mstest/nunit attribute based style.

I have read various posts about the subject and searched Google and found a few interesting tips (like this: [.NET benchmarking frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163143/net-benchmarking-frameworks)).

The tools I seem to be able to find on NuGet and Google all seems to be smaller experimental tools. And in that case I might be better of doing something we have the full control over.

The question is, do any one have experience setting this up, can anyone recommend a tool, or am I best of creating my own testrunner to get something that fits our framework precisely.

The basic requirements are:

- Able to measure either time or a number as a result
- For algorithmic tests determine a number of loops to run the code to get an average
- For database tests, be able to run something up front that doesn't count as test time (e.g. clear SQL cache or setup our framework)
- Output data either in database or in some sort of structered format (mstest trx format would be really nice for easy CruiseControl.Net support

Additional requirements could be

- Ways to group tests results, e.g. all tests of a given module or class could be bundled
- Reporting abilities - show graphs, detect trends (is test over time becoming slower)

As I list the requirements it feels it might be very specific, and thus I will be better of implementing our own small framework. In that case I think something like outlined below.

**TestRunner**

- Look for test classes based on attribute, execute all methods with test attribute, store result (either in file, direct output or database)

**TestMethods**

Something like

```
[Benchmark]
public TimeSpan Job_GetAllRows_TimeOnColdCache()
{
    //Arrange
    ...

    //Act
    return Measure( () => Job.GetAllRows());
}

[Benchmark]
public int Job_GetAllJobs_CallsToDatabase()
{
    //Arrange
    ...
    Database.NumberOfQueriesExecuted = 0;

    //Act
    Job.DoHeavyCalculation();

    return Database.NumberOfQueriesExecuted;
}

[Benchmark]
public TimeSpan Job_HeavyCalculation_AverageTimeToCalculate()
{
    //Arrange
    ...

    //Act
    return Measure(Measurement.Average, 1000, () => Job.DoHeavyCalculation());
}
```

The Measure class is just a wrapper over starting a Stopwatch, and do a try-finally and return Stopwatch elapsed time in finally.

I hope someone has a comment on this - and ideally has experience with a framework that solves the above and is ready to use.

Comment: Have you tried [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/)? It is continuous testing but also includes performance metrics. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: I have a colleague why has/had NCrunch installed. I will check it out. I will expect it to measure the entire test, which causes me to have a lot of "framework" plumbing time included as well, which minimizes the visibility of a degrading test performance in the Code Under Test. At least in MS Test the TestInitialize methods are (correctly I may add) included in the overall test time. So it doesn't let me pinpoint the lines of code I want to measure.

Comment: You could just routinely use a performance analyser like JustTrace from Telerik which requires no code modifications and uses reflection to datamine the information about which method calls/processes are taking long.
http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx

I don't think you can integrate this into a build process tho'.

Comment: We are already using ANTS Performance Profiler to investigate performance problems - but as you state this is not fit for automatic build integration. But once we detect a performance problem tools like that are invaluable for determining the cause. Never ever **think** you know where the bottleneck is - use a profiler to determine. :-)