# Why one loop is performing better than other memory wise as well as performance wise?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have following two loops in C#, and I am running these loops for a collection with 10,000 records being downloaded with paging using "yield return"

First

```
foreach(var k in collection) {
  repo.Save(k);
}
```

Second

```
 var collectionEnum = collection.GetEnumerator();
 while (collectionEnum.MoveNext()) {
   var k = collectionEnum.Current;
   repo.Save(k);
   k = null;
 }
```

Seems like that the second loop consumes less memory and it faster than the first loop. Memory I understand may be because of `k` being set to `null`(Even though I am not sure). But how come it is faster than `for each`.

Following is the actual code

```
  [Test]
    public void BechmarkForEach_Test() {
        bool isFirstTimeSync = true;
        Func<Contact, bool> afterProcessing = contactItem => {
            return true;
        };

        var contactService = CreateSerivce("/administrator/components/com_civicrm");
        var contactRepo = new ContactRepository(new Mock<ILogger>().Object);
        contactRepo.Drop();
        contactRepo = new ContactRepository(new Mock<ILogger>().Object);

        Profile("For Each Profiling",1,()=>{
            var localenumertaor=contactService.Download();
            foreach (var item in localenumertaor) {

            if (isFirstTimeSync)
                item.StateFlag = 1;

            item.ClientTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;

            if (item.StateFlag == 1)
                contactRepo.Insert(item);
            else
                contactRepo.Update(item);

            afterProcessing(item);


        }
        contactRepo.DeleteAll();
        });

    }


    [Test]
    public void BechmarkWhile_Test() {
        bool isFirstTimeSync = true;
        Func<Contact, bool> afterProcessing = contactItem => {
                                                                 return true;
        };

        var contactService = CreateSerivce("/administrator/components/com_civicrm");
        var contactRepo = new ContactRepository(new Mock<ILogger>().Object);
        contactRepo.Drop();
        contactRepo = new ContactRepository(new Mock<ILogger>().Object);

        var itemsCollection = contactService.Download().GetEnumerator();

        Profile("While Profiling", 1, () =>
            {
                while (itemsCollection.MoveNext()) {

                    var item = itemsCollection.Current;
                    //if First time sync then ignore and overwrite the stateflag
                    if (isFirstTimeSync)
                        item.StateFlag = 1;

                    item.ClientTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;

                    if (item.StateFlag == 1)
                        contactRepo.Insert(item);
                    else
                        contactRepo.Update(item);

                    afterProcessing(item);

                    item = null;
                }
                contactRepo.DeleteAll();

            });
    }

    static void Profile(string description, int iterations, Action func) {

        // clean up
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        // warm up 
        func();

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            func();
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.Write(description);
        Console.WriteLine(" Time Elapsed {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

I m using the micro bench marking, from a stackoverflow question itself [benchmarking-small-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047218/benchmarking-small-code-samples-in-c-can-this-implementation-be-improved)

The time taken is

- For Each Profiling Time Elapsed 5249 ms
- While Profiling Time Elapsed 116 ms

Comment: Seems unlikely, can you disassemble both loops with [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) and compare the result?

Comment: You say download and save, those operations are typically heavy and can vary between each execution, have you done multiple measurements and analyzed average and variance?

Comment: Is collection strongly typed? e.g. A generic collection. I'm wondering if 'repo.Save' method has overloads and different methods are called.

Comment: Setting `k` to `null` has no effect at all on memory usage (unless you run it in debug mode...). The garbage collector already knows that the reference is not used any more even before you assign null to the variable.

Comment: There are two differences that I can point out for certain here. First, in "second" (unlike "first") there is no exception handling around the call to `MoveNext` that will be found in code generated for a `foreach`. Second, `k` is declared inside the loop in "second" where in a `foreach` it will be declared outside (hence the warnings for "access to modified closure" when capturing that variable in an expression). Can't speak to why second would be necessarily faster though - wouldn't happen to be a 32-bit app would it?

Comment: How does it "seem"? How are you measuring? Actually, the second is *worse*, as you aren't disposing the enumerator.

Comment: @mlorbetske I'd have to check, but I don't recall any specific exception handling around MoveNext() in the expansion. Just a try/finally (essentially a "using") to dispose the enumerator. Edit: I checked, and indeed, tht isn't there: http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/15.8.4.htm

Comment: @marc that's what I was referring to, you're right, I should have been more clear

Comment: I have updated the question. Please have a look at the actual code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `foreach` version calls `var localenumertaor = contactService.Download();` inside the profile action, while the enumerator version calls it outside of the `Profile` call.

On top of that, the first execution of the iterator version will exhaust the items in the enumerator, and on subsequent iterations `itemsCollection.MoveNext()` will return false and skip the inner loop entirely.

Comment: Thanks a ton Lee for this catch this was a typo let me fix and then compare.. thanks ..