# Impact on preformence of async tasks every second

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

I'd like to know what impact that calling a handler every second can make in a website performence.

I ask this because i've an auction website and i'd like to see live bidding, so how can i do it without losing performence in the website.

What options do i have to make this perfect or almost!!

Comment: Try to simulate your conditions and do a benchmark test like so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047218/benchmarking-small-code-samples-in-c-can-this-implementation-be-improved

Comment: How about abandoning polling and using something like SignalR instead? Much lighter on load. Much more responsive. http://signalr.net/

Comment: definitely signalR, look at their ChatRoom Example