# how to read all text from all txt files(*.txt)

Tags: c#

I need use the fastest method(in my opinion it is readalltext) how to readalltext from txt files,i do not know how to correct the code:

```
string[] files = Directory
  .GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Wiz\Desktop\test","*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var letter = File.ReadAllText(files);
```

Comment: Read msdn for [`GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) parameters and return values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles` returns possibly multiple files, `File.ReadAllText(files)` reads the text of a single file. Clear? You need a loop on `files`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interesting thing for me was to point out, which is the FASTEST way, and therefore i tried 3 techniques:

### **Overview**

[image: overview] *~200 Ticks

### **Conclusion**

Parallel Approch works best in this Case, `Directory.EnumerateFiles` is much faster than `Directory.GetFiles` (searched with pattern *.txt and Subdirectories inclued)

### Code

A - GetFiles and ReadAllText

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Program Files (x86)", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
   var a = File.ReadAllText(file);
}
```

B - EnumerateFiles and ReadAllText

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\Program Files (x86)", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
   var a = File.ReadAllText(file);
}
```

C - Parallel Approach

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\Program Files (x86)", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
Parallel.ForEach(files,(current) => 
{
    var a = File.ReadAllText(current);
});
```

FEEL FREE to add ideas, thoughts, ....

Comment: difficult to define the BEST method, it depends if searching files or reading files is the heavier duty in a specific case...

Comment: forgot: `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel` is available since .Net Framwork 4.0

Comment: sorry @CodeCaster , don't know what mean exactly - could you please explain what's missing in your opinion? For profiling i used this function (100 iterations): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047218/benchmarking-small-code-samples-in-c-can-this-implementation-be-improved

Comment: one more question:
if i have i one txt file word image1,2,3 and in the other txt file letters a b c etc.
how should i read files, that will be like this:

image1 a
image1 a
image1 a
image2 b
image2 b
image2 b
image3 c
image3 c
image3 c
it means that if file with image is reading finished but is not reading finished second file, first file is starting read again in (for) until the second file is not reading until end.

Answer (score 2):

`File.ReadAllText` is expecting the path to one file but `Directory.GetFiles` returns a array of files. So you have to use a loop / linq to get the text of each file

```
string sDir = @"C:\Users\Wiz\Desktop\test";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
string[] letters = files.Select(x => File.ReadAllText(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: everything is good, but anyway i did not get what i really wanna

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a loop to read all the files as [ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) will read one file at a time.

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    // Do the reading of your file here.
}
```