# Performance on text data files

Tags: c#

Is there a faster alternative approach to the following code:

```
 bool isAlphabeticOnly(String strin)
        {
            foreach (char c in strin)
            {
                if ((c < 'a' || c > 'z') && (c < 'A' || c > 'Z'))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your benchmarking code, so that people can test their alternative suggestions against yours.

Comment: Probably not _significantly_ faster.  - you short circuit, and are doing fast comparisons.  Are you sure your logic is right?

Comment: Also, is this a bottleneck in your app?  Why are you worried about its performance when there are likely other parts of your app that _can_ be made faster?

Comment: Are you sure that you want "Résumé" to be a "non-alphabetic" word?

Comment: @Heinzi what do you mean by benchmarking code?

Comment: @RehanKhan: You are asking whether there is a faster alternative to your code. So I assumed that you *measured* the speed of your code (this is what benchmarking does) and determined it to be insufficient. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1047218/87698

Comment: @DStanley In the above code, I am checking if a string contains only alphabetic characters and its giving me the correct output. What do you mean by am I sure my logic is right?

Comment: @DStanley There must be other parts of my app that i can make faster but I've to start from somewhere - correct?

Comment: Yes - _you start at the slowest part_.  You can't make a bicycle faster by making the seat more aerodynamic.   Get a decent profiler, determine which part of your app is the slowest, and tackle that first.

Comment: @RehanKhan : _Résumé_ **!=** _Resume_.

Comment: @RehanKhan Logic with ANDs, ORs NOTs, and `<`/`>` can be tricky.  Is's very easy to get the logic wrong and get bad results.  I'm not saying it _is_ wrong - just making sure you've thoroughly tested all edge cases.

Comment: @DStanley Almost all my logics in this app involve ANDs, ORs, NOTs and `</>`. How to determine slowest part? By clicking `Debug All` and run each command at a time and note the time taken for completion of its execuation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this implementation is a bit faster (but *less readable*)

```
bool isAlphabeticOnly(String strin) {
  // comparison with 0 - "i >= 0" - is faster than with strin.Length
  for (int i = strin.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    char c = strin[i];

    if ((c < 'a' || c > 'z') && (c < 'A' || c > 'Z'))
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

At my workstation (.net 4.5, IA64, Core i5 3.2GHz) average times are

```
  Initial 2100 ms
  This    1600 ms
```

Measuring

```
 // Yes, very long string 
 String test = new String('p', 100000000) + new String('Q', 100000000);

 Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

 sw.Start();

 isAlphabeticOnly(test);

 sw.Stop();
```

However, if you experience real *performance problems*, it's not `isAlphabeticOnly` where you should solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've `IsDigitsOnly` , `isPunctuation`, & `isAlphaNumberic` alongwith `isAlphabeticOnly`. I'll implement your suggested logic (`comparison with 0 - "i >= 0" - is faster than with strin.Length`) in all of them. What else I should check for better performance?

Comment: @Rehan Khan: you can try using `Parallel.ForEach` and alike, but this will do on *large* strings only (multithreading adds *overhead*)

Comment: Used `.NET Profiler` to find out the slowest part of my code. Changed its logic and its performance is at least 85% gone faster.

Answer (score 0):

I only tested with Cat - you need to put all letters in
Not sure if this is faster but worth testing

```
HashSet<char> hsAz = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 't', 'C' };
bool isAlphabeticOnlyHash(String strin)
{
    for (int i = strin.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
    {
        if (!hsAz.Contains(strin[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've tried and got `7100` milliseconds (while the initial solution has `2100`) at my workstation. It was worth testing, but in *this particular case* computing hash is slower operation than direct comparison.

Comment: @RehanKhan What part of "Not sure if this is faster but worth testing" was not clear?

Comment: @RehanKhan You ingrate.  You asked a question and I put out a valid idea to try and was open about that.  This is a free site and we are not obligated to benchmark.

Comment: @Paparazzi Sorry I missed reading "Not sure if this is faster but worth testing" part of your answer. Thanks for your time and answer. Appreciate it mate.