# What is the preferred way of sorting List<T> by multiple criteria?

Tags: c#

I have an in-memory list containing around 1 million records with multiple columns (Date, Name, Value, Id,.....)

My question: What is the best solution (i.e. giving best performance) for sorting such a large list by multiple columns?

Example (pseudo-code):

```
list.orderbyDesc(name).thenBy(Name).thenBy(Value)
```

Comment: What research have you done on how to sort a `List`?  What did you find?  What problems did you have implementing the solutions you found in your research?

Comment: i think about sortset but i think it's not enough with my need performance

Comment: How you data is stored? Is it just a `List` in memory? How do you get it?

Comment: @TrườngSơn What was the specific implementation you wrote up?  What did you find in your performance tests?  How far below your requirements was it?

Comment: @enkryptor yes, my list are in memory.

Comment: @TrườngSơn how do you get it in memory? Do you use some kind of database? The pseudo code you've provided seems like it is supposed to work with `IQueryable`, not `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Check it out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/

Answer (score 1):

There are in principle two ways to sort your generic List:

- Using a Linq method chain:

  ```
  var orderedEnumerable = list.OrderByDescending(item => item.Property0)
      .ThenBy(item => item.Property1)
      .ThenBy(item => item.Property2);
  ```
- Using a custom comparer implementing `IComparer<T>`. With the comparer you can either create a new ordered enumerable

  ```
  var orderedEnumerable = list.OrderBy(item => item, new MyComparer());
  ```

  or you can sort in-place using the `Sort()` method:

  ```
  list.Sort(new MyComparer());
  ```

Try benchmarking the different approaches (Hint: I'd expect the in-place `List<T>.Sort(IComparer<T>)` to run fastest in principle, but it all depends whether you are going to enumerate the entire result of `Enumerable.OrderBy`).

Here is a simple benchmark sample to play around:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public double Salary { get; set; }
}


class RecordComparer : IComparer<Record>
{
    public int Compare(Record x, Record y)
    {
        // Sort by Name, Age, and then Salary
        if (x.Name != y.Name) return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
        if (x.Age != y.Age) return x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age);
        return x.Salary.CompareTo(y.Salary);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static Random _random = new Random();
    static List<Record> _list;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Profile("SortUsingLinqMethodChain", 50, InitList, SortUsingLinqMethodChain);
        Profile("SortUsingLinqComparer", 50, InitList, SortUsingLinqComparer);
        Profile("SortUsingListSort", 50, InitList, SortUsingListSort);
    }

    static void InitList()
    {
        _list = new List<Record>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            _list.Add(new Record { Name = RandomString(12), Age = RandomAge() });
        }
    }

    static void SortUsingLinqMethodChain()
    {
        // NOTE: the `ToList` materialization may not be necessary at all
        //    This totally depends on what you want to do with the result.
        _list = _list.OrderBy(item => item.Name)
                     .ThenBy(item => item.Age)
                     .ThenBy(item => item.Salary).ToList();
    }

    static void SortUsingLinqComparer()
    {
        // NOTE: the `ToList` materialization may not be necessary at all
        //    This totally depends on what you want to do with the result.
        _list = _list.OrderBy(item => item, new RecordComparer()).ToList();
    }

    static void SortUsingListSort()
    {
        _list.Sort(new RecordComparer());
    }

    // based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/1344242/40347
    public static string RandomString(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[_random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }

    public static int RandomAge()
    {
        return _random.Next(100) + 1;
    }

    public static double RandomSalary()
    {
        return _random.NextDouble() * 100000;
    }

    // based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/1048708/40347
    static double Profile(string description, int iterations, Action init, Action func)
    {
        // Run at highest priority to minimize fluctuations 
        // caused by other processes/threads
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
        Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

        // warm up 
        init();
        func();

        var watch = new Stopwatch();

        // clean up
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            init();
            watch.Start();
            func();
            watch.Stop();
        }

        Console.Write(description);
        Console.WriteLine(" Time Elapsed {0} ms", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        return watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
```