# visual studio 2017 start with/without debugging performance difference

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to visual studio. I created a console application in vs2017 to test the performance of a library, the code is very simple, something like

```
start stopwatch
insert a bunch of elements to a list. 
stop stopwatch
print out the time used
```

The strange thing is that when I run it within visual studio 2017, the time used is drastically smaller when running under "start without debug", i.e control+f5, comparing to "start with debug". 
I wonder what is causing the difference and which number should I use as a benchmark once I deployed this console app to cloud.

Thanks.

Comment: You will want to analyze performance in Release mode without a Debugger as that's how your program will run in production. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047218/benchmarking-small-code-samples-in-c-can-this-implementation-be-improved. There's also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385749.aspx for a more general approach to performance analysis

Answer (score 0):

Running on a development/developer machine cannot be considered as a benchmark for performance measurement. The best practice is to have a performance test[preferably automated] which is executed regularly on a machine which is as close as possible to your production environment. The test should capture the time taken for the use cases that you are interested in bench marking.